# d3 transitioning barchart with variable length

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a barchart with 8 bars. Now i want to create a barchart with 10 bars inckuding a transition. The transition works fine, but my new barchart has just 8 bars too.
My html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TransitionTest</title>
    <script src="d3.v2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="TransitionTest.js"></script>
    <button onclick="transitioning()">
        Transition
    </button>

</body>
</html>
```

My Script:

```
var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var height = 500;
var width = 1000;
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,10])
            .range([0,width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,9])
            .range([height,0])

var bar = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function (d,i) {
            return xScale(i);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return yScale(d);
        })
        .attr("width", function (d,i) {
            return (99);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return (height-yScale(d));
        })
        .attr("fill", "grey");

function transitioning() {
data = [8,6,4,2,0,9,7,5,3,1];
bar.data(data)
    .transition()
    .attr("x", function (d,i) {
        return xScale(i/2);
    })
    .attr ("y", function (d) {
        return yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("width", function (d,i) {
        return (49);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return (height-yScale(d));
    });
}
```

**What am I doing wrong**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the new bars using the `enter()` selection, similar to how you add the bars in the first place. So in your function `transitioning()` you need to have another call like

```
bar.data(data).enter().append("rect")...
```

You can make the bars "appear" by setting the height (and/or width) to 0 first, then call `transition()` and set them to the actual values. See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) for more detail on the different selections/joins.

Answer (score 0):

Now I changed my transition function to this:

```
function transitioning() {
if (i==1){
    data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
    i=0;
}
else if (i==0){
    data = [8,6,4,2,0,9,7,5,3,1];
    i++;
}

bar.data(data).enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("x", function(d,i) {
    return xScale(i);
})
.attr("y", height)
.attr("height", 0)
.attr("width", 99)
.attr("fill", "grey")
.transition()
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return (height-yScale(d));
})
.attr("width", 99)
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d);
});

bar.transition()
.attr("x", function(d,i) {
    return xScale(i);
})
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d);
})
.attr("height", function(d) {
    return (height-yScale(d));
})
.attr("width", 99)
.attr("fill", "grey");

bar.exit().transition()
.attr("y", height)
.attr("height", 0)
.remove();
}
```

And it works except the exit() function. I got on each click a change of my barchart, but the last 2 bars from the longer data wont disappear. When I use firebug I can see, that every time when I switch to the longer data array 2 new bar elements are generated. How can I get them to be deleted?